# Movie is playing on iPad and iPhone simulators but isn't on iPod touch 2G

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

I have an app with embedded videos in it. When I start playing a video, it works great on the iPad and iPhone simulators, but on the iPod touch it doesn't start. I can see only a black screen with the "Loading movie" text and it stays like this forever.

I have tried different formats, even the sample video from the Apple website, but nothing works on the iPod touch.

Answer (score 0):

This is the version problem, something doesn't match there, like the version on the device and he version on computer, I came across this when implemented my project to different devices. Or you may have used some deprecate functions not suitable any more.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have checked my settings and devices. Both my iPhone and iPod Touch are running with ios 4.2.1. My base SDK and ios deployment target are set to 4.2, and I don't think that I am using any deprecate functions, because I have no warnings and it should not work on the iPhone too if that was the case.